# Multiple cells in UITableView With Different array sizes for each cell

Tags: ios, swift3, uitableview

I'm working on a project in Swift 3.0 where I have a `UITableView` with three custom cells. In the first one I just have a label, in the second one I have an image plus a label along with expandable and collapsible headers.Thus I have three different sections for the second cell. And lastly the third one is also contains just a label. Im stuck at the delegate methods since these three cells returns three different arrays where the count is different that will return. The code I've done partially as bellow. As of now the code is only the second cell (which is working). But I think I've done the `cellForRow` method correctly.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tblSwift: UITableView!

    var arrayForTableView = ["swift","objective-c","c#","java"]
    var arrayForIcons = ["swift.jpeg","objectiveC.jpeg","csharp.jpeg","java.jpeg"]
    let dictSection = [["swift 1.0","swift 2.0","swift 3.0"],["objectiveC 1.0","objectiveC 2.0"],["C# 1.0","C# 2.0"],["java 1.0"]]

    let cellItentifir = "cellText"
    var expanedSections = [true, true, true, true]

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        // The bellow code is for the expandable and collapsible cells
        return arrayForTableView[section]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        let headerView : UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        headerView.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow.withAlphaComponent(1.0)
    }

    func tapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {   // The bellow code is for the expandable and collapsible cells
        if let tag = sender.view?.tag{
            expanedSections[tag] = !expanedSections[tag]
        }
        tblSwift.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let headerView = UITableViewHeaderFooterView()
        headerView.tag = section

        let tapRecog = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))

        tapRecog.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapRecog.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        tapRecog.delegate = self
        headerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecog)
        return headerView
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return arrayForTableView.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {

        let isExpanded = expanedSections[section]
        if(!isExpanded) {
            return 0
        }
        return dictSection[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FirstCell")
             cell?.textLabel?.text = "First Cell"
            return cell!
        }else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.cellItentifir)
        cell?.textLabel?.text = dictSection[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(named:arrayForIcons[indexPath.section])
        return cell!
        }else{

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ThirdCell")
            cell?.textLabel?.text = "Third Cell"
            return cell!

        }
    }
```

Comment: what issue happens here ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider **section** instead of indexPath in condtion.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
      if section == 1 {
        let isExpanded = expanedSections[section]
        if(!isExpanded) {
            return 0
        }
        return dictSection[section].count        
       }
      else {
        return 1;
        }
}
```

**Now CellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FirstCell")
             cell?.textLabel?.text = "First Cell"
            return cell!
        }else if section == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.cellItentifir)
        cell?.textLabel?.text = dictSection[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(named:arrayForIcons[indexPath.section])
        return cell!
        }else{

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ThirdCell")
            cell?.textLabel?.text = "Third Cell"
            return cell!

        }
    }
```

Comment: this is partially right but the issue is when assigning  headers to sections, because i only need headers for the section 1, where it has four subsections

Comment: use this function for set height per your needs : func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if section == 1 {
            return 150
        }
        return 50
    }

Comment: BAsed on my code what should I do in func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        // The bellow code is for the expandable and collapsible cells
        return arrayForTableView[section]
    }